# PHP Chat Bot: Google Talk

Tags: php, gmail, xmpp, bots

I was wondering how to create a chat bot for Google Talk via special client.

I know it uses XMPP to send messages, but I do not know how to use this at all. It is my understanding that I should be able to make a bot which chats for me when I am away if I were to create my own client page, which would parse the chats with my data. Where would I begin if I wanted to create a custom client, and how could I make it parse messages and autorespond in a set manner? My intended usage: autoresponder for when I am AFK, with a decent AI (which I can make.)

Can I use this protocol with PHP to make my bot, or must it be java or python based?

Thanks for any and all help!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [xmpphp](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/) library should help you. Have a look at the examples.

PHP is absolutely the last language I would use for something like this (well, okay, I wouldn't do it in awk or sed either), but if you're set on using it, you can.

Comment: Awesome!

I am set on using php. It will be much easier for me in the long run.

Comment: +1 FOR using PHP. Why not? It depends on what you're going to do with it. You know you can also access Growl with PHP. If you're going to send off messages for important events, debugging, etc. (granted you don't want 50,000 messages)...I think it's an extremely convenient manner of doing so. You have the ability to inform several people at the same time, have it pop up in your face, and more. Use your noggins. PHP is a great language and while yea there's node.js and other better things for full blown chat and asynchronous messaging...There's still value in the unexpected and the "convenient"

Answer (score 4):

Give a look to this library:

- [xmpphp](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/)

Gives you a fully OOP API (> PHP5) to communicate using this protocol.

By default it uses TLS so you will not have any problems connecting to the talk google server.

Check this code example:

```
<?php
include("xmpp.php");
$conn = new XMPP('talk.google.com', 5222, 'username', 'password', 'xmpphp',
                 'gmail.com', $printlog=False, $loglevel=LOGGING_INFO);
$conn->connect();
$conn->processUntil('session_start');
$conn->message('someguy@someserver.net', 'This is a test message!');
$conn->disconnect();
?>
```

Comment: What is TLS? Does my web server need to support it, or is that only needed by the gmail server?

Comment: Transport Layer Security (http://is.gd/1ZOkz) is a secure communication protocol, the Google Talk servers wrap the XMMP sessions under this protocol, so all the messaging and the entire session, travels encrypted on the network. Your PHP instalation must have OpenSSL support (http://is.gd/1ZPOD)