# Google API: Notify about Calendar Entry Change via Google Talk

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-talk

I have a calendar and some Users in Google Talk, which I'd like to notify when the event has changed.

So I will need to use the Calendar API and the Talk API, both are enabled in the API Console.

Does anyone have an idea how I could make use of this? Preferably using PHP.

Maybe this has been done before or is usable by other people. Thanks in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

You barely need the Talk API; Google Talk is XMPP - have a look at this question for connecting with PHP:

[PHP Chat Bot: Google Talk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220340/php-chat-bot-google-talk)

Also, it does look someone has done something similar already, in java:

http://code.google.com/p/notifical/